# use oracle and sql server to read tables from Dynamics CRM 2013 database

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013. I need to have a real time view into the entity tables inside of Microsoft Dynamics CRM using an oracle database, an SQL database and Microsoft Access. I need to understand the methods for all 3 database types.

By real time view - I mean a view into the data in CRM Dynamics table. If a user changes a value, the value should be reflected inside the view in near real time. Similar concept to a Microsoft access linked table. The view does not need update or write rights, simply need to read the data from the entities in these three database formats.

Is this possible in CRM dynamics 2013? If yes can someone point me to a resource where I can learn to do so.

Comment: There is auditing in Dynamics CRM. You should look into that (it needs turned on in the application by entity). Most likely it will be sufficient for you to query the audit tables to get what you need.

Comment: https://www.fmtconsultants.com/tracking-changes-in-on-premise-crm-2011-audit-view-using-sql/ This article is for CRM 2011 but should apply to 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for SQL replication across different RDBMS from CRM.

Options: Research on scribe replication or your own data integration using delta pulls in SSIS or window services.

After online 2015 update 1 - we have [change tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932130(v=crm.7).aspx) feature to do integration.

Audit table can be a good starting point if you want to explore but it's not easily consumable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are very few (if any) CRM 2013 online instances left. Would it be safe to assume that your environment is on-premise?

While I have not done this myself, I believe that Oracle, SQL, and Access all allow linking to a SQL server. You could theoretically link the three "consumer" systems to CRM's SQL instance and have them query CRM's filtered views directly.